# How to count angle between vector and horizontally oriented vector?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I need to calculate in my Java application an angle between my line and horizontal line that has the same beginning. I have a line described by its equation:

$$f(x) = ax + b.$$

I would like to know angles alpha and beta in degrees. From this equation I can compute few points that lie on both lines and use it for computation. An angle between horizontal line and another two lines is max. 90 degreees.

**Edit:** now I am in my problem in this stage:

I have three points and I need to calculate an angle between them:

```
start = {x, y}
end1 = {x, y}
end2 = {x, y}
```

I create two vectors that these three points define a move them into beginnig of coordinate system:

```
vector1 = [{end1.x - start.x}, {end1.y - start.y}]
vector2 = [{end2.x - start.x}, {end2.y - start.y}]
```

Now I count the angle between these two vectors (in radians):

> radians = ({vector1.x * vector2.x} + {vector1.y * vector2.y}) /
>   (vector1Length * vector2Length);

then I convert (in Java) radians into degrees.

**Question:**

When I apply above mentioned technique with these three points:

```
start = {0, 0}
end1 = {1, 0}
end2 = {1, 1}
```

it calculates 1.41 radians what is **81 degress**, but in my opinion it should be **45 degrees**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to brackets and *arccosine* functions, you missed them in your code.

radians = **arccos((** {vector1.x * vector2.x} + {vector1.y * vector2.y} **)** / vector1Length * vector2Length **)**;

Comment: In my code I have brackets, it's not the problem.

Comment: I am sure you miss the arccosine, check that too. And make sure you are calculating length with the right formula: `len(v)=sqrt(v.x*v.x + v.y*v.y)`.

Comment: Yes, calculating of length is correct. My value for counting arccos is 1.414213562373095 (numerator = 2.0, denominator = 1.4142135623730951) and this is not able Java function Math.acos convert to arc cosine. I don't know what I am still doing wrong.

Comment: How did you get numerator 2, it should be 1? Double check your code in that part.

Comment: Uff, I am an idiot. Instead of "*" sign I had a "+" - plus sign. Thanks, you are awarded and your help is accepted.

Comment: One more question - A=[1.0, 1420.0], B=[5.0, 1420.0], C=[5.0, 1556.0] and I need to compute angle between AB and AC. Result is 0.029399051601892736 arccos what is 88.3 degreees. But when I plot it (see - http://s4.postimg.org/dzylxdcy5/2013_03_27_123125.png), it should not be more than 50 degreees. What is wrong?

Comment: That plot is not quite right, look at the scales of x and y axises. If you want to see the actual angle you must have the same scale on both of them. Imagine $AB=4mm$ and $BC=136mm$, do you see how big is angle $CAB$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

For vectors $\vec{x} = (x_1, x_2)$ and $\vec{y} = (y_1, y_2)$, the cosine of angle between them is given by your formula.

$$ \cos \theta = \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{\|\vec{x}\| \, \|\vec{y}\|}.$$

You need to use the *arccosine* (also called *inverse cosine*) function to recover $\theta$.

$$ \theta = \arccos \left( \frac{\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}}{\|\vec{x}\| \, \|\vec{y}\|} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks, I know it from Wikipedia, I need to implement it.